# Using custom tags with HTMLPurifier

Tags: video, audio, tags, htmlpurifier

I want to use  and  tags as well as some custom tags (for example , ) with HTMLPurifier. I used

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed','audio, video');
```

to add those tags but received warning that they are not standard and the tags are stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Purifier doesn't support HTML5 yet, so that won't do. You can try to jerry-rig something with http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html but audio and video might be a bit fiddly to do correctly. Note also that even if audio and video were allowed, you're not allowing any attributes or other tags, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'video[src|type|width|height|poster|preload|controls]');  Element 'video' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)